# undefined offset and syntax error but code is executed properly

Tags: php

ajax:

```
... 
success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
```

**position.php**

Two arrays are transfered (`$ids` and `$indexes`), with the equal number of elements.

```
extract($_POST);

print_r($ids);
print_r($indexes);

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($ids); $i++) {
    $stmt = $db->query("UPDATE " . $table . " SET inde = " . $indexes[$i] . " WHERE id = " . $ids[$i]); // this is line 10
}
```

The code is executed properly, i.e. all table data are updated as expected, but console (after listing the arrays) shows some errors:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 25
        [1] => 23
        [2] => 18
        [3] => 26
        [4] => 21
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 4
    )

<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 5 in <b>D:\matria\s02\admin\position.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064... near 'WHERE id =' at line 1 in D:\matria\s02\admin\position.php:10
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `for` cycle:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($ids); $i++) {
```

`count($ids)` is 5 and when `$i` reaches 5, 5 <= 5 is still true. However, indexing starts from 0, therefore your possible indexes are between 0 and 4. Change your `for` to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
```

and then it will not try to do things when `$i` reaches 5.

EDIT:

The original answer dealt with your effective error, but there are still things to be refactored/improved after the fix:

- you have an array called `$indexes` which on its own indexes stores the index as value as well. If there is no counter-example unmentioned in the question, then this whole array is redundant and you can remove `$indexes` and you can use `$i` instead of `$indexes[$i]`
- your `$i < count($ids)` in the for cycle will calculate the number of `$ids` on each iteration. It is much more elegant to calculate it only once before the `for` with something like `$myCount = count($ids);` and then use `$i < $myCount` in your `for`, to calculate things only once

Suggested code:

```
extract($_POST);

print_r($ids);

$myCount = count($ids);
for ($i = 0; $i < $myCount; $i++) {
    $stmt = $db->query("UPDATE " . $table . " SET inde = " . $i . " WHERE id = " . $ids[$i]); // this is line 10
}
```